# How to ensure App component is loaded before displaying another component

Tags: reactjs

Am using facebook login in my application following [this](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/04/06/react-jwt-authentication-tutorial-example) and backend is redirecting to main application with user token which I parse and store to be used across the application, I currently have a `PrivateRoute` to make sure only logged-in user have access to that page, but it seems loading order is causing me an issue

**App.JS**

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('setting user in App.js') // prints second
    let token = Cookies.get('token')
    if (token) {
      var decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      let user = decoded.user
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.parse(user));
      userService.currentUserValue = JSON.parse(user);
    }
    else {
      userService.currentUserValue = null;
    }
  }

 render() {
    return (
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/users/:id/profile/" component={Profile} />
)}
```

**PrivateRoute**

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest}
        render={props => {
            const currentUser = userService.currentUserValue;
            console.dir('PrivateRoute currentUser is',currentUser) // prints first
            if (!currentUser.facebook_id) {
                // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
                return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
            }
            // authorised so return component
            return <Component {...props} />
        }} />
)
```

when the page loads, I get an error that user wasn't found and console logs shows that ... `PrivateRoute` loaded before `App` finishes its logic.
How can I solve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use state to store info about user into your App.js. Initial value to be set as null, and componentDidMount checking user info and updates the state.
This can be used for further decision if to show some children components or not :

```
return {user && <ChildrenComponent /> || 'waiting for user info...'}
```